# Does MapR have scalable machine learning algos. Like Mahout?

Tags: machine-learning, mapreduce, mahout

I am specifically wondering if MapR has Kmeans clustering just like Mahout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, MapR is only a "faster" Hadoop. There are no algorithms included.

So your jobs should be compatible.

But what is the deal in implementing your own? K-means is ultra simple. See my blog post:
http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/05/k-means-clustering-with-mapreduce.html

However I have implemented a k-means clustering with BSP (Bulk Synchronous Parallel) and Apache Hama which is almost ten times faster if you compare it with the Mahout benchmark results in this book: http://www.manning.com/ingersoll/ (linked jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-588)
Here is the benchmark of k-means with Apache Hama: http://wiki.apache.org/hama/Benchmarks

You can find it here:
https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/clustering/KMeansBSP.java

Comment: MapR is not just a faster Hadoop.  It includes all of the standard ecosystem components as well.  This includes Mahout.

Comment: You are definitely correct that Hadoop's map-reduce implementation is not suitable for iterative algorithms like traditional k-means using Lloyd's algorithm.  There is a JIRA open that will allow single-pass k-means analysis.  Being single-pass, this algorithm would not require multiple passes through the data, nor would it require multiple invocations of map-reduce in order to work.  The speedups should be comparable to what Thomas describes.